# PHP function to capitalize only words within a dictionary

Tags: php, function

I want a function to capitalize only the words not contained in a text file (my own dictionary).

```
function capitalize($x, $e ='utf-8') {
        if (function_exists('mb_strtoupper') && function_exists('mb_substr') && !empty($x)) {
            $x = mb_strtolower($x, $e);
            $upper = mb_strtoupper($x, $e);
            preg_match('#(.)#us', $upper, $matches);
            $x = $matches[1] . mb_substr($x, 1, mb_strlen($x, $e), $e);
        } else {
            $x = ucfirst($x);
        }
        return $x;
    }
```

This code works to capitalize the first letter. But I want it to compare each word with a text file and only capitalize the words that exist in that file and leave the other words as is from the same text.

For example, as a string:

```
ACCESS PONIT WIRELESS-N600 DUAL BAND WITH POE SMB
```

Text file

```
with
access
ponit
```

Result:

```
Access ponit WIRELESS-N600 DUAL BAND with POE SMB
```

Now I saw this code on a different [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103702/php-to-capitalize-all-letters-including-after-a-slash-except-for-certain-words)

```
<?php
$major = 'accounting technology/technician and bookkeeping';
$major = preg_replace_callback("/[a-zA-Z]+/",'ucfirst_some',$major);
echo ucfirst($major);

function ucfirst_some($match) {
   $exclude = array('and','of','the');
   if ( in_array(strtolower($match[0]),$exclude) ) return $match[0];
   return ucfirst($match[0]);
}
```

But I dont know how to make it work all together

Comment: Is the input already all capitalized

Comment: the input is all in capital letters. By capitalize I mean only the first letter of the full sentence. my Code does this, but now I need it to do an exception to the words that dont exist in a text file.